# scanf("%[^\n]",command) inside while loop

Tags: while-loop, scanf

I want to have an infinite loop
getting command each loop,

and this is my code

```
while ( 1 )
{
    char * command[100];
    printf("---| ");
    scanf( "%[^\n]",command);
    printf("%s\n",command);

}
```

for some reason it only inputs once and 
the loop doesnt terminate with asking the input.

what did i do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition should be

char command[100];

And not char *command[100] - this is a array of 100 char pointers.

Also scanf() is not easy to use, I would use `fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);`
and then remove the newline.

```
while ( 1 )
{
    char command[100];
    printf("---| ");
    scanf( "%s", command);
    printf("%s\n",command);
}
```